# how to enquote variable names in r ggplot wrappers

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, rlang, ggh4x

I would like to write custom wrappers for facets in ggplot and have problems handling variable names.

What I would like to achieve:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  ggh4x::facet_manual(vars(cyl %>% 
                             recode('4' = "four", '6' = "six", '8' = "eight") %>% 
                             factor(levels = c("four", "six", "eight"))), 
                      design = matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2), 
                      scales = "free") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = hp))
```

Now I would like to build a wrapper around this complex facet formula:

```
my_facet <- function(x) {
  ggh4x::facet_manual(vars(x %>% 
                             recode('4' = "four", '6' = "six", '8' = "eight") %>% 
                             factor(levels = c("four", "six", "eight"))), 
                      design = matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2), 
                      scales = "free") 
}

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  my_facet(x) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = hp))
```

But since x is not in the environment but in `mtcars`, this does not work:

```
Error in recode(., `4` = "four", `6` = "six", `8` = "eight") : 
  object 'x' not found
```

I have tried several tricks that change `x` in the `my_facet` function, such as `sym(x)`, `!!sym(x)`, `enquo(x)`, `{{x}}`, but nothing works.

What kind of variable handling is required here?

Comment: Is `x` a variable in the global environment? Is its value `"cyl"`?

Comment: yes. my bad. {{x}} works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. Is the idea you want to reference a variable `x <- "cyl"` in the global environment?

```
my_facet <- function(x) {
  ggh4x::facet_manual(vars( {{x}} %>% 
                             recode('4' = "four", '6' = "six", '8' = "eight") %>% 
                             factor(levels = c("four", "six", "eight"))), 
                      design = matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2), 
                      scales = "free") 
}

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  my_facet(cyl) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = hp))
```